# How to set the TCP parameters in NS2 for packet generation

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, network-protocols, ns2

I am working in NS2 and trying to mix the tcp and udp packets, by using MD1 queue type. I want to split the arrival rate between each udp and tcp packets. I have managed to set the udp as Poisson traffic and found out how to control the generation of packets, but in tcp I haven't figured out how I can control the generation of packets meaning how to set the arrival rate in tcp source traffic, (I will be using ftp and cbr traffic). I have tried many ways but I haven't managed to solve it. Which parameter in the .tcl file for tcp should I use to do that?

My .tcl file:

```
    set ns [new Simulator]

    set tf [open output.tr w]
    set nf [open nam.nam w]

    $ns trace-all $tf
    $ns namtrace-all $nf

    proc finish {} {
            global ns nf tf
            $ns flush-trace
            close $tf
        close $nf
        exec nam nam.nam &
            exit 0
    }

        set n0 [$ns node]
        set n1 [$ns node]
        set n2 [$ns node]
        set n3 [$ns node]

        $ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 1Mb 10ms DropTail
        $ns simplex-link $n1 $n2 1Mb 10ms DropTail
        $ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 0.04Mb 10ms DropTail

        $ns queue-limit $n0 $n2 100
        $ns queue-limit $n1 $n2 100
        $ns queue-limit $n2 $n3 100

    $ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n2 orient right-down
    $ns simplex-link-op $n1 $n2 orient right-up
    $ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n3 orient right

    $ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n2 queuePos 0.5
    $ns simplex-link-op $n1 $n2 queuePos 0.5
    $ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n3 queuePos 0.5

    set udp [new Agent/UDP]
    $ns attach-agent $n1 $udp
    set null [new Agent/Null]
    $ns attach-agent $n3 $null
    $ns connect $udp $null

    set exp  [new Application/Traffic/Exponential]
    $exp  attach-agent $udp
    $exp  set burst_time_ 0
    $exp  set idle_time_ 400ms
    $exp  set rate_ 1mb
    $exp  set packetSize_ 1000

    set tcp [new Agent/TCP]
    $tcp set class_ 2
    $ns attach-agent $n0 $tcp

    set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
    $ns attach-agent $n3 $sink
    $ns connect $tcp $sink
    $tcp set window_ 20
    $tcp set packetSize_ 555

    set ftp [new Application/FTP]
    $ftp attach-agent $tcp
    $ftp set type_ FTP

    $ns at 0.2 "$exp start"
    $ns at 0.3 "$ftp start"
    $ns at 30000 "$exp stop"
    $ns at 30000 "$ftp stop"
    $ns at 30000 "finish"
        $ns run
```

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried and explain what didn't work about it. The more specific you are, the more likely you are to get answers.

Comment: update >> code is posted up